# Can I make direct calls from my app (Flutter Android & IOS)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, android-dialer

Actually, I'm trying to create a dialer app. From which you can call directly by typing mobile number.
I know of the "url_launcher Flutter package" but it is not suitable for my application. I want like the default dialer of mobile, so that you can call directly by selecting a SIM.
Please help me!
[image: as shown]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This package help you to call number's directly from your app:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phone_direct_caller